# How can I use binary search to search for the first item in a List greater than a specific value for C# 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, binary-search

In Fact for my situtation, there are two condition

```
class A
{
    double value;
    public double Value{get;set;}
}

A[] arr = {....} 

double val;
```

I want to search for this val in arr, but val may not in the list than 
A[i].Value > val && val < A[i+1].Value

in some conditions, I need A[i]. In other conditions I need A[i+1] 
I try like arr.ToList().BinarySearch(A, Acomparer) but i couldn't
this array has about 550 element I am trying to optimize this search

Thanks advance for help

Comment: Binary search can only work if the collection is sorted. Make sure items are put in order while adding or use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx) with a custom [`IComparer<A>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) that compares objects based on their `Value`:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<A>
{
    public int Compare(A x, A y)
    {
        return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var index = Array.BinarySearch(arr, val, new MyComparer());
if (index >= 0) {
    // val found at index
}
else {
    // ~index is "i + 1" in your example
}
```

Comment: Better yet, create a generic comparer that can be initialized with a delegate. That removes most of the clutter.

Comment: Am I missing something? How does this work if the array does not contain val?

Comment: @JamesGaunt BinarySearch returns a meaningful index even if the value is not in the array.

Comment: @usr oh yes - I just read that in the documentation - very nifty!

Comment: sorry, but I am confused index>= 0 means if the value exists in list, but if not in list then this Array.BinarySearch(arr, val, new MyComparer()) return what -negative value?

Comment: @Doctor: Yes, the documentation fully describes that. In practical terms, `~index == i + 1` for the definition of `i` in your example.

Comment: yeap sorry about that you right, it is described in Return Value Part of Documentation i missed this part :))) and thanks all of you